# How to upload image using angularjs php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Is there any working **angularjs**, **php**, and/or **mysql** for uploading 
base 64 image file?

Any answer will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is. But actually we're here to help with specific programming problems, not to code / google for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic & http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - You'll find that by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can upload any image or file using AngularJs follow the below steps.
Note here I am uploading the file to store in a folder and not to the database because it's a bad idea to upload the file into the database instead of that store the file into folder and name of the file in the database.

Step 1: Create the simple view in HTML as below:

```
<form name="upload_file" id="upload_file" ng-submit="functionName();">    
    <input type="file" name="inputfieldname">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Now in angular controller write the function as below:

```
$scope.functionName = function() {
 var formdata = new FormData();
 var filename = document.getElementById('upload_file').files[0];

 formdata.append('filename', filename);

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'action.php',//Put your php file url
        data: formdata,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    }).then(function successCallback(result) {

        $scope.message = result.data;
        alert($scope.message);

    });
}
```

Comment: My problem is what if I host my app and theres many users, can they view of what i've upload.?